# can oracle DRCP be used with PHP PDO?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I've set up Database Resident Connection Pooling in an oracle database.
Once configured, I can use a couple of methods to obtain a persistent connection from the pool:

```
$conn = oci_pconnect('scott', 'tiger', 'ORCL_POOL');
```

Alternatively, I can use Zend\Db:

```
$db = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'persistent' => true,
    'username' => 'scott',
    'password' => 'tiger',
    'driver' => 'oci8',
    'instance' => 'ORCL_POOL', //configured in tnsnames with (SERVER=POOLED)
));
```

So far so good, and I can see that connections are being reused from the pool via oracle views such as `V$CPOOL_CC_STATS`

I have a 3rd party library which uses PDO, and I can't work out how to configure it to use persistent connections. The `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` option sounds good, but seems to use its own connection cache (gets a fresh connection every time, and shows up as a 'miss' in `V$CPOOL_CC_STATS`).
eg:

```
$pdo = new \PDO('oci:dbname=ORCL_POOL', 'scott', 'tiger', 
                array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

So it's using OCI to connect, and I've told it to use persistent connections...?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a support agreement with Zend, and I raised this with them. Their response, which they said quotes Oracle documentation and 'The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual', was:

> PDO_OCI with DRCP is not a workable solution, due to the very issues
>   you are experiencing > (PDO wants to maintain its own cache of
>   persistent connections.) As you may be aware there is also no reliable
>   information on the web regarding the two as a cohesive unit. --->
>   (PDO_OCI with DRCP)
>
> The reasoning behind this is because Oracle Best Practices and the
>   Underground PHP and Oracle Manual, states that PHP OCI8 must be used.
>   It has a better feature set, performance, reliability and stability.
>   Use of PDO_OCI for general purpose applications is "NOT" recommended.
>   Also as you are aware via your own testing DRCP can be used with
>   oci_pconnect(), or using Zend\Db with the 'persistent' option.
>
> Starting with Oracle Database 11g, PHP OCI8 can do connection pooling
>   with Database Resident Connection Pooling (DRCP).

As a workaround, however, there are a few libraries around (such as https://github.com/taq/pdooci) that extend the base PDO class and implement the features via oci_* calls. Importantly for my use case, PDO's persistent connection option is implemented with `oci_pconnect`.

Comment: The real reason is that PDO_OCI doesn't use Oracle's "session pool" which is the technology that talks to the DRCP servers.  PHP OCI8 does use session pooling internally.